# Insert a Binary string into MYSQL varchar column

Tags: mysql

As we all know, we will use the mysql_query api to send a query to the server, and the query are passed by a string as the parameter. And we will have to formulate the string outside the mysql_query called by some C functions like sprintf.For example,

```
sprintf(buffer, “insert into table(describe) values(‘%s’)”, strA);
mysql_query(..., buffer);

The ‘describe’ is a VARCHAR(150).
```

In some special cases, one of our functions will cat several C style string into a long one remaining all the ending ‘\0’ to form a binary, ie in C form catting “abc” and “efg” into “abc\0efg\0”, of course with the length given out to the caller(in this case, it is 8). However, the out binary can NEVER be used in the sprintf above as strA, as the C functions will truncate the string by meeting the first ‘\0’.

Is there anything special we can do to fulfill our needs? We want to insert a binary into a column defined as VARCHAR. We have tried to change all the ‘\0’ into ‘\0’ literally, which seems to work good but time and codes consuming. Is there any alternative easier method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) to escape this string.